# Is there a way to search and replace in macro text in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you can help me.

I have consolidated a number of workbooks into one. In the sheets, there are macros to ease navigation (jump to macros). However, they are all linking to the old workbooks, so whenever I press a macro in the new workbook, Excel tries to open the old workbook.

Essentially, the macros look like this:

```
'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/teams/Folder/Shared Documents/General/File2.xlsm'!Jump_X_to_Y'
```

Instead of:

`Jump_X_to_Y`

Now, I can manually replace the macros, but it will take me ages.

**Is there a way to search and replace, so that I could simply remove all the external Sharepoint links in one-go?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, in the VBA editor, Edition menu,--> Replace.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "In the sheets, there are macros"?

Comment: Good point, Rory. I. meant that I have buttons with macros to navigate the sheet. Thanks, Foxfire, will try.

Comment: I realize I have posted my question rather poorly.

I have buttons with assigned macros that can help navigate a sheet. However, since I copied sheets from indiviual workbooks into on consolidated workbook, the assignmed macros redirect me to a different file instead of helping me navigate the new sheet. I need to remove the file reference, i.e. the entire sharepoint link, so that it works. But we are talking 150+ buttons, which takes a long time manually. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean [Hyperlinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink). A Hyperlink is a feature where you can click on text and it opens a web-page or another Workbook, or moves focus to another part of the worksheet.

To change a Hyperlink using VBA, you can search the worksheet cells and get the `Hyperlinks` collection for the whole worksheet. Then you can check and change the `Address` for each hyperlink as needed.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim HL As Variant
    For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        If InStr(1, HL.Address, "sharepoint", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            HL.Address = Split(HL.Address, "!")(1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: They are not hyperlinks, but rather Buttons with Macros like these assigned to them:

Sub Jump_air_ship()
'
' Jump_air_ship Makro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=67
    Range("A129").Select
End Sub